# What is a single word describing this type of statement?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Scenario: A gang from the west of the USA wants to kill gang members from the east of the USA. The gang from the west meet a gang member from the east and ask:

'Where are you from?'

The gang member from the east replies:

'From the west.'

But he intends to mean 'the western world' so he said something intending a different meaning than that of the meaning in the minds of those he was addressing, thus fooling them, and saving himself.

Is there a term for this type of linguistic/semantic strategy?

*Note: no offense to people from the USA*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an answer can be interpreted different ways, especially with intent to deceive, it's an [equivocal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equivocal) answer, and the act of answering this way is [equivocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation).

Comment: Is there a single term which is used only for this type of statement which is intended to deceive?

Comment: Yes, it's equivocation.  Or you might say prevarication.  Either works.